# Change color of sequential ellipse in a loop

Tags: loops, colors, fill, p5.js

so for this project I need to change the color of each ellipse so that it's a different color than the ellipse before it and remains that color until it goes off the canvas and gets reset. I commented a few things I tried that didn't seem to work out.

Here's the hint my instructor gave :When you are using a loop to create objects, your counting variable is different each time you go through the loop, so you can use this to help create colors that are different each loop as well. But do not use random, as this will make the colors change every single time, rather than merely ensuring each tile/monster is different from it's neighbors but always the same color. For example if the very first tile is blue and the second tile is green, they should always be blue and green.

Any help or advice y'all could give would be appreciated. I've been at this for a few hours and I've seem to hit a block so I could use some fresh eyes.

```
var monster;
var grassColor;
var dirtColor;
var tileSize;
var redDead;
var meanGreen;




function setup () {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

monster = {
    x: 0,
    y: 20,
    size: 30,
    spacing: 50,
    speed: 1,
    color: color(75, 198, 98),
    message: "Moving",
  };


  grassColor = color(122, 229, 80, 20);
  dirtColor = color(160, 104, 30);
  tileSize = 25;
  tileColor = color(145, 32, 200);
 meanGreen = color(0, 200, 155);
 redDead = {
   r: 50,
   g: 10,
   b: 35,
};

}
function draw () {
  background(grassColor);
  stroke(dirtColor);
  strokeWeight(1);

  // #4 Draw a tile floor // Bonus Challenge

for (var tileX = 0; tileX <= width; tileX += tileSize) {
for (var tileY = 0; tileY <= height; tileY += tileSize) {
    fill(tileColor);
  rect (tileX, tileY, tileSize, tileSize);

}
 }




 //#3 Make the monsters move diagonally

monster.x += monster.speed;
monster.y += monster.speed;

if (monster.y > 0){
  monster.x = monster.y;
}


// #2 Use a loop to draw copies of monster along the x-axis


 while (monster.x <= width ) {
  fill (monster.color);
   strokeWeight(1);
   stroke(dirtColor);
   ellipse(monster.x, monster.y, monster.size, monster.size);
  strokeWeight(5);
   stroke(0);
   point(monster.x + 1, monster.y + 3);
   monster.x += monster.spacing;
   //while (monster.x % 3 && monster.x <= width) {
     //monster.color = color(redDead.r, 198, 98);
    //redDead.r += 25;
   //}
 }


if (monster.x > width) {
  monster.x =0;
}

if (monster.y > height){
  monster.y = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is only one `monster`. This is an object with attributes (`x` position, `y` position, `color`,... ) What you need is an array of `monsters`.

In `setup`, instead of doing

```
  monster = {
      x: 0,
      y: 20,
      size: 30,
      spacing: 50,
      speed: 1,
      color: color(75, 198, 98),
      message: "Moving",
    };
```

you should do something like

```
monsters = []
spacing = 50
for(var i=0; i < 8; i++) {

  monsters[i] = {
      // each positions will be different
      x: spacing * i,
      y: 20,
      size: 30,
      speed: 1,
      // each colors will be different
      color: color(random(255), random(255), random(255)),
      message: "Moving",
    };
}
```

now you have yours differents `monsters` and in `draw` you do what you was doing for your `monster` object for each monster in your `monsters` array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < monsters.length; i++) {

  monsters[i].x += monsters[i].speed;
  monsters[i].y += monsters[i].speed;
  // ...
  // all your draw code with monsters[i] insteed of monster
}
```

obviously you don't need the `while` loop and the `monster.x += monster.spacing;` line in this new version of your programm.

---

This is the way to do it without modifiying your code a lot. But you really should look at Object-Oriented Programming in Javascript. This is what you need for doing it properly and this will be really usefull for futures improvments of your programm. Check [the 6.1 to 7.3 videos of Daniel Shiffman about it](http://%20https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xG2Vbnv0wvg&index=19&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6Zy51Q-x9tMWIv9cueOFTFA) if you want a simple overview of the subject

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually watching his videos right now haha